# IE contenteditable div selection

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I've been trying to make my newer website complaint for all browsers while reducing lag for an input. I made a div as the container that is contenteditable and each line as its own div and acts as a line. This works great for every browser but IE here's an example of the issue: [IE selection resize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8wNn.png). I do not want to make each line contenteditable because doing so will not allow the user to highlight more than one line of text. My code looks like this:

```
<div contenteditable>
    <div class='inner'>BLA BLA</div>
    <div class='inner'>BLA BLA</div>
</div>
```

All help is appreciated, if I didn't specify well enough please comment.

Comment: What is the actual issue? Can you not edit the lines? Is it a display issue? You image isn't very helpful, we need some description of what you expect vs. what is happening.

Comment: which IE Version are u using ?

Comment: Im using IE 11 and I just want to remove the 10px weird border thing they put around it when focusing. It makes it very unpleasing to edit because you cant see the line above it very well.

Comment: IE sometime has parsing or default values issues, have u tried setting it ? i mean contenteditable="true" ?

Comment: I have but no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any way, if u want to change that, youre talking about styles, this is the way you can handle the styles:

```
[contenteditable="true"]:active,
[contenteditable="true"]:focus{
   border:none;
   outline:none;
}
```

maybe this can fix ur issue, give it a try

Comment: Sadly it didn't work, I don't believe its an issue that can be fixed with border or outline.